# How can I pass a class method as a parameter to another function and later call it, preferably making the variable class method signature explicit?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

If I have a class that needs to call a parent class method with a class method as parameter I can do it with `std::function` + `std::bind` as shown below:

```cpp
class A {
    void complexMethod(std::function<void()> variableMethod) {
        // other stuff ...
        variableMethod();
        // some other stuff..
    }
}

class B : public A {
    void myWay() {
        // this and that
    }

    void otherWay() {
        // other and different
    }

    void doingSomething() {
        // Preparing to do something complex.
        complexMethod(std::bind(&B::myWay, this));
    }

    void doingAnotherThing() {
        // Different preparation to do some other complex thing.
        complexMethod(std::bind(&B::otherWay, this));
    }
}
```

How would I need to change the above code to implement the same thing using templates instead of `std::function` + `std::bind`?

And how about lambdas instead of `std::function` + `std::bind`? I still want to call `B:myWay()` and `B::otherWay()` but using lambdas. I don't want to substitute `B:myWay()` and `B::otherWay()` with lambdas.

Is there any implementation technique (one of the above or some other) were I would be able to make `variableMethod` return type and parameters explicit? How would I do it? Let's say the signature of `variableMethod` is:

```cpp
    bool variableMethod(int a, double b);
```

Which technique is recommended? Why (speed, flexibility, readility...)?

Comment: This may be a long shot, but maybe take a look at the [command design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) or the [template-method](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/template-method/cpp/example). As what you are trying to achieve maybe is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) and there are perhaps better solutions if you give more info.

Comment: Yes @RobinDillen, I see where you are coming from but right now I am dealing with this issue as an oportunity to better understand templates and lambdasin C++. But yes, depending on the actual situation a completely different solution might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I need to change the above code to implement the same thing
> using templates instead of `std::function` + `std::bind`?
>
> And how about lambdas instead of `std::function` + `std::bind`? I
> still want to call `B:myWay()` and `B::otherWay()` but using lambdas.
> I don't want to substitute `B:myWay()` and `B::otherWay()` with
> lambdas.

You can use a lambda, yes.

Something like `[this]() { return myWay(); }` that:

- captures `this`, and
- calls a method of the current object.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/nq6EezPTa)

```cpp
#include <iostream>  // cout

class A {
protected:
    template <typename F>
    void complexMethod(F&& f) { f(); }
};

class B : public A {
    void myWay() { std::cout << "myWay\n"; }
    void otherWay()  { std::cout << "otherWay\n"; }
public:
    void doingSomething() {
        complexMethod([this]() { return myWay(); });
    }
    void doingAnotherThing() {
        complexMethod([this]() { return otherWay(); });
    }
};

int main() {
    B b{};
    b.doingSomething();
    b.doingAnotherThing();
}

// Outputs:
//
//   myWay
//   otherWay
```

> Is there any implementation technique (one of the above or some other)
> were I would be able to make `variableMethod` return type and
> parameters explicit? How would I do it?

You could use `const std::function<bool(int,double)>& f` as the parameter receiving a function for `complexMethod`. And still pass a lambda. Notice though lambdas are now receiving `(int i, double d)` (it could be `(auto i, auto d)` as well).

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/a8jM7cxd1)

```cpp
#include <functional>  // function
#include <ios>  // boolalpha
#include <iostream>  // cout

class A {
protected:
    bool complexMethod(const std::function<bool(int,double)>& f, int i, double d)
    { return f(i, d); }
};

class B : public A {
    bool myWay(int a, double b) { return a < static_cast<int>(b); }
    bool otherWay(int a, double b)  { return a*a < static_cast<int>(b); }
public:
    bool doingSomething(int a, double b) {
        return complexMethod([this](int i, double d) {
            return myWay(i, d); }, a, b);
    }
    bool doingAnotherThing(int a, double b) {
        return complexMethod([this](auto i, auto d) {
            return otherWay(i, d); }, a, b);
    }
};

int main() {
    B b{};
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << b.doingSomething(3, 5.5) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << b.doingAnotherThing(3, 5.5) << "\n";
}

// Outputs:
//
//   true
//   false
```

Notice also the same could be accomplished with templates, although you wouldn't be making the signature explicit.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/djaYdrvna)

```cpp
#include <functional>  // function
#include <ios>  // boolalpha
#include <iostream>  // cout

class A {
protected:
    template <typename F, typename... Args>
    auto complexMethod(F&& f, Args&&... args) -> decltype(f(args...))
    { return f(args...); }
};

class B : public A {
    bool myWay(int a, double b) { return a < static_cast<int>(b); }
    bool otherWay(int a, double b)  { return a*a < static_cast<int>(b); }
public:
    bool doingSomething(int a, double b) {
        return complexMethod([this](auto i, auto d) {
            return myWay(i, d); }, a, b);
    }
    bool doingAnotherThing(int a, double b) {
        return complexMethod([this](auto i, auto d) {
            return otherWay(i, d); }, a, b);
    }
};

int main() {
    B b{};
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << b.doingSomething(3, 5.5) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << b.doingAnotherThing(3, 5.5) << "\n";
}

// Outputs:
//
//   true
//   false
```

> Which technique is recommended? Why (speed, flexibility,
> readility...)?

Item 34 of Scott Meyer's Effective Modern C++ book is titled `Prefer lambdas to std::bind`. It ends with a summary saying: `Lambdas are more readable, more expressive, and may be more efficient than using std::bind`. However, it also mentions a case when `std::bind` may be useful over lambdas.

Comment: Great @rturrado. That's exactly waht I was looking for. Can you just explain what the "(F&& f)" really means in the complexMethod signature?

Comment: That's a universal reference; it would be useful in case you had to forward `f` somewhere else, because it allows you to preserve its value category (lvalue or rvalue). In this example, since the lambda function is an rvalue, it just uses it without copying it. With `template <typename F> void complexMethod(F f)` it would copy it before using it.

Comment: Ok @rturrado. One last doubt: why a simplier ```template <typename F> void complexMethod(F& f)``` doesn't work and I need a universal reference to avoid copying the lambda?

Comment: You cannot cast an rvalue to a non-const lvalue; but you could use `const F&` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Template + lambda solution:

```cpp
struct A
{
    template <typename F>
    void runA(F func)
    {
        cout << 1 << endl;
        func();
        cout << 3 << endl;
    }
};

struct B : A
{
    int number = 2;

    void runnable() { cout << number << endl; }

    void runB()
    {
        cout << 0 << endl;
        runA([this]() { runnable(); });
        cout << 4 << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    B variable;
    variable.runB();
}
```

In order to take a function as template parameter, just take in a template type of that function like above. [lambdas](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) can be used instead of bind to make things easier (`this` is passed to lambda captures list).

Explicitly declaring the arguments:

```cpp
void run_func(std::function<bool(int, double)> func)
{
    bool b = func(10, 10.01);
}
```

`std::function` allows you to define your arguement and return types like above.

Comment: Here you transformed the called function "F func" in your code to a lamba. Maybe I didn't explained myself well. I still want to call my original class methods (B:myWay() and B::otherWay() in my original code) but using lambdas instead of std::bind.

Comment: Oh I didn't get that. I updated my answer to include that.